# Indy 10 IDFTP -'Read Timed Out' Error while listing the files

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

I am using Indy's `TIdFTP` for FTP access. `TIdFTP.List()` raises a "Read Timed Out" error.  This happens only on one server (Server 2016 OS, which is my production server). `TIdFTP.List()` works perfectly on other servers with Server 2012 OS, which is my development machine.  As per the documentation, I played around with the `ReadTimeOut` and `TransferTimeOut` properties, but still the same error occurs.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Try 'Passive' mode *myFTP.Passive := True;*

Comment: @mjn42- Thank you very much.It worked :-)

Comment: To elaborate, Passive mode transfers make an *outbound* TCP connection *from* the client *to* the server, whereas Active mode transfers make an *inbound* TCP connection *from* the FTP server *to* the client.  Passive mode transfers are more friendly to firewalls/routers, whereas Active mode transfers are frequently blocked by non-FTP-aware firewalls/routers.